# Bayes factor and hypothesis test in Bayesian inference

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, bayesian, inference, bayes-factors

Let 
$$\pi_0=P(\theta\in\Theta_0)=\int_{\Theta_0}\pi(\theta)d\theta$$
$$\pi_1=P(\theta\in\Theta_1)=\int_{\Theta_1}\pi(\theta)d\theta$$
$$a_0=P(\theta\in \Theta_0|x)$$
$$a_1=P(\theta\in \Theta_1|x)$$

in this case for test $$H_0:\theta\in\Theta_0\space vs \space H_1:\theta\in\Theta_1$$
the decision rule is
$$\text{Reject}\space H_0\space \text{if}\space a_0<a_1$$

I also know that Bayes factor is $$B=\frac{a_0\pi_1}{a_1\pi_0}$$
and that is as the likelihood ratio. But how is the decision rule using $B$ if I want to test things like

i)$H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ vs $H_1:\theta>\theta_1$

ii)$H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ vs $H_1:\theta<\theta_1$

iii)$H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ vs $H_1:\theta\neq\theta_1$

?

It's not so clear to me how I use the Bayes factor in hyphotesis test.

Comment: In all those hypothesis tests, you are given a different $\Theta_1$. From there you just apply the derivation of the Bayes factor, which will obviously depend on the choice of $\Theta_1$.

Comment: @Xi'an What derivation of Bayes factor?